# SQL: getting COUNT for each N

Tags: sql

Is there a way to count the times every unique `like_user_id` is in the rows?
Adding onto this; is there a way to output this to a table with `like_user_id` and `count`?

I've already tried the following, but this only does it for `like_user_id` = `2`.

Here's the table I have. [link](https://gyazo.com/78d91b773619d09dde2ac606f79814c1)

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`like_user_id`) FROM `xf_liked_content`
WHERE `xf_liked_content`.`like_user_id` = 2;
```

Comment: I've added the sample table data already & the expected result:   like_user_id - count /
1 - 1 /
2 - 3 /

Comment: plz see the link referenced to know on , how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I'll definitely use that next time, thanks for that! Answers that work have, however, also been given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is actually very simple.

All you need to do is to group them by the term `like_user_id` and select it, and its count!
Here is a full example:

```
SELECT like_user_id, count(like_user_id) FROM xf_liked_content GROUP BY like_user_id
```

There are a lot of constraints on how to use `GROUP BY`, for instance AFAIK, you cannot `SELECT` a term that is not on your `GROUP BY` list, but this is no issue in your case. For more information on the `group by` statement, please check https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp.

Enjoy programming!

Comment: It's quite the opposite actually.. with most databases you cannot select something that's not in the group by, but grouping without selecting is perfectly fine

Comment: Oh, that's right! Feel free to edit my answer, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code:

```
select 'like_user_id', count(*) as cnt
from 'xf_liked_content'
group by 'like_user_id'
```

Or this, diffenetly depends on your DBMS:

```
select "like_user_id", count(*) as cnt
from "xf_liked_content"
group by "like_user_id"
```

Or next code:

```
select like_user_id, count(*) as cnt
from xf_liked_content
group by like_user_id
```